# Create custom DataType Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to make my own validation class (i have a lot of validation methods in JS that i want to translate into C# to use with MVC models) that works exactly like data annotations do, validating in client and server side: `[DataType(MyDataType)]` or like a Validation DataAnnotation Attribute like this: `[MyDataTypeValidation]`

i don't know wich option is better to make my validation "library"

In example i have my class FigurasDA and i want to make my custom validation to the attribute nombre.

```
namespace MonitoreoIntegrado.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(FigurasDA))]
    public partial class Figuras
{
}

public class FigurasDA
{
    [DataType(MyDataType)]
    //or
    [MyDataTypeValidation]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
}
```

so in this case, i want to validate that the string matches the regexp `@"^[\w\s\.\-_]+$"` and shows a error message like this "Solo se permite letras, numeros y puntuaciones(- _ .)" if don't. (this is my "Alfanumerico" datatype).

Can you give me an example where to put my validation class and what code write inside?.

Comment: Have you tried the `RegularExpressionAttribute` ex:`[RegularExpression(@"pattern", ErrorMessage="")]`? Or you can extend one of the `ValidationAttribute` classes.

Comment: I want to use this regexp in a lot of classes. so i need a class i guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually it's easy... You just have to inherit you custom validation attribute from `ValidationAttribute` class and provide your own `IsValid` logic. For example:

```
public class MyDataTypeValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^[\w\s.-_]+$");          

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {               
        if (_regex.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Solo se permite letras, numeros y puntuaciones(- _ .)" );
    }
}
```

and in your view model you can use:

```
public class FigurasDA
{    
    [MyDataTypeValidation]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

You can save this validation attribute, for example in `Attributes` folder in your MVC project:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Comment: @Clamari, wherever you want in your solution/project. You can create folder named `Attributes` and put there all your custom validation logic.

Comment: In a DataValidation.css file inside my project root IE?

Comment: @Clamari, css is cascade style sheet file, it contains html page styles. I provided some screen shots for example, see my edits.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo. DataValidation.cs it was just an extra "s" haha thanks a lot :).